# Grouping arrays and 2D arrays into a single 2D array with the same length for all

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, jagged-arrays

The final result must always contain 6 values in each index:

```
[
   [value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4,value_5,value_6],
   [value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4,value_5,value_6]
]
```

Position of the values:

| Object | Positions |
| --- | --- |
| `menu` | `value_1` |
| `home_team` | `value_2` and `value_3` |
| `empty array` | `value_4` |
| `away_team` | `value_5` and `value_6` |

Possible arrays can be:

| Object | Option 1 | Option 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `menu` | `[]` | `[[-],[-],[-],[-],...]` |
| `home_team` | `[]` | `[[-,-],[-,-],[-,-],[-,-],...]` |
| `empty array` | `[]` |  |
| `away_team` | `[]` | `[[-,-],[-,-],[-,-],[-,-],...]` |

```javascript
function if_empty(the_list) {
  if (the_list.length > 0) {
    return the_list
  } else {
    return [[null,null]]
  }
}

function group_arrays() {
  const menu = [
    ['abcd'],
    ['1234']
  ];

  const home_team = [];
  const ht = if_empty(home_team);

  const away_team = [
    ['val1', '0001'],
    ['val2', '0002'],
    ['val3', '0003']
  ];
  const at = if_empty(away_team);

  const collection = [menu, ht, [], at];
  const output = Array(Math.max(...collection.map((a) => a.length)))
    .fill()
    .map((_, i) => collection.flatMap((a) => a[i]));

  Logger.log(output)
}
```

But as you can see, index 0 has 6 values and the others have only 5:

```
[
  [abcd, null, null, null, val1, 0001],
  [1234, null, null, val2, 0002],
  [null, null, null, val3, 0003]
]
```

But I need that regardless of where values are missing, they must always be aligned with 6 values each:

```
[
  [abcd, null, null, null, val1, 0001],
  [1234, null, null, null, val2, 0002],
  [null, null, null, null, val3, 0003]
]
```

What should I readjust in my code to get around this problem?

I notice that the cause of this is in the 2D arrays that when they don't have values, they only generate 1 empty value instead of 2 empty values as expected by me.

Comment: From your showing script, I confirmed that you are using `Logger.log`. `Logger.log` is for Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) So, I added a tag of `google-apps-script`. If this was not required to be added. Please remove the tag.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Yes, it's about ```google-apps-script``` too, I'm adjusting the arrays to send to a Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, for example, the value of `let collection = [menu, ht, [], at];` is `[[["abcd"],["1234"]],[[null,null]],[],[["val1","0001"],["val2","0002"],["val3","0003"]]]`. In this case, `Math.max(...collection.map((a) => a.length))` is `3`.
- When your script of `const output = Array(Math.max(...collection.map((a) => a.length))).fill().map((_, i) => collection.flatMap((a) => a[i]));` is run, at `collection.flatMap((a) => a[i]))`, when `i` is `0`, `["abcd"]`, `[null,null]`, `null`, `["val1","0001"]` are used. By this, 6 elements are included.
- When your script of `const output = Array(Math.max(...collection.map((a) => a.length))).fill().map((_, i) => collection.flatMap((a) => a[i]));` is run, at `collection.flatMap((a) => a[i]))`, when `i` is `1`, `["1234"]`, `null`, `null`, `["val2","0002"]` are used. By this, 5 elements are included.

  - I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

If my understanding is correct, I thought that in your script, it might be required to expand `collection` of `let collection = [menu, ht, [], at];` to the same length for each element.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function if_empty(the_list) {
  if (the_list.length > 0) {
    return the_list
  } else {
    return [[null, null]]
  }
}

function group_arrays() {
  const menu = [
    ['abcd'],
    ['1234']
  ];

  const home_team = [];
  const ht = if_empty(home_team);

  const away_team = [
    ['val1', '0001'],
    ['val2', '0002'],
    ['val3', '0003']
  ];
  const at = if_empty(away_team);

  // --- I modified below script.
  let collection = [menu, ht, [], at];
  const maxLen = Math.max(...collection.map((a) => a.length));
  collection = collection.map(a => a.length != maxLen ? [...a, ...Array(maxLen - a.length).fill([...Array(a[0] ? a[0].length : 0)].fill(null))] : a);
  // ---

  const output = Array(Math.max(...collection.map((a) => a.length)))
    .fill()
    .map((_, i) => collection.flatMap((a) => a[i].length == 0 ? null : a[i]));

  console.log(output)
}

group_arrays();
```

- In this modification, in my modified script, `[[["abcd"],["1234"]],[[null,null]],[],[["val1","0001"],["val2","0002"],["val3","0003"]]]` is converted to `[[["abcd"],["1234"],[null]],[[null,null],[null,null],[null,null]],[[],[],[]],[["val1","0001"],["val2","0002"],["val3","0003"]]]`. By this, your expected values are retrieved.

#### Testing:

When the above script is run, you can see the following value at the log.

```json
[
  ["abcd",null,null,null,"val1","0001"],
  ["1234",null,null,null,"val2","0002"],
  [null,null,null,null,"val3","0003"]
]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, because I'm going to send it to a spreadsheet and if they don't all have the same amount of values, it generates an error in ```setValues()``` about the amount of number data columns being different from the amount of number columns in ```getRange()```. Thanks for support!

Comment: @Digital Farmer Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the inner array length `rowLength` as a property of the  specific array object like `home_team` and access it in `if_empty` and insert  `null` array accordingly:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 

const if_empty = /*modified*/(the_list, rowLength) =>
  the_list ? the_list : Array(rowLength).fill(null);

function group_arrays() {
  const menu = [['abcd'], ['1234']],
    home_team = [],
    away_team = [
      ['val1', '0001'],
      ['val2', '0002'],
      ['val3', '0003'],
    ],
    collection = [menu, home_team, [], away_team];

  /*modified*/home_team.rowLength = 2;
  const output = Array.from(
    Array(Math.max(...collection.map((a) => a.length))),
    (_, i) => collection.flatMap((a) => /*modified*/if_empty(a[i], a.rowLength))
  );

  console.log(output);
}
group_arrays();
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```